# What format is this string in?

Tags: ios, iphone, encoding, format, dataformat

I'm trying to figure out what data an iPhone game app is sending. It uses the [`GKTurnBasedMatch`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedMatch_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKTurnBasedMatch) framework.

I've captured some of its packets and I found a promising XML message with this string as the value for a `game-state` key:

```
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
```

Base64, of course! So I decoded it and got:

```
{"GameGuid":"bd120afb-3c64-4e76-937a-fe1628e1db57","GameData":"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"}
```

Looks like a dict with another Base64 string in the `GameData` key. However, Base64 decoding *that* gives me a bunch of binary data:

```
02 01 14 c2 a9 69 f2 22 d1 bd 5c 10 7d 6f 96 b4 .....i."..\.}o..
e1 e2 9c 55 a3 51 ac 6d e7 5c a5 dc c2 c2 37 6c ...U.Q.m.\....7l
3e 2e 07 7d 89 23 b1 6d 11 6f bf 0e a0 da e4 ab >..}.#.m.o......
d9 18 17 4d cc aa 73 d6 17 b9 f7 55 15 ed 60 b9 ...M..s....U..`.
```

which is uncompressible:

```
>>> len(game_data)
4114
>>> len(game_data.encode("zlib"))
4125
```

It's not zlib-encoded:

```
>>> game_data.decode("zlib")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#126>", line 1, in <module>
    game_data.decode("zlib")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\zlib_codec.py", line 43, in zlib_decode
    output = zlib.decompress(input)
error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

And it's not even zlib without the header:

```
>>> def inflate(data):
    import zlib
    decompress = zlib.decompressobj(
            -zlib.MAX_WBITS  # see above
    )
    inflated = decompress.decompress(data)
    inflated += decompress.flush()
    return inflated

>>> inflate("roflcopters".encode("zlib")[2:])
'roflcopters'
>>> inflate(game_data)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#130>", line 1, in <module>
    inflate(game_data)
  File "<pyshell#128>", line 6, in inflate
    inflated = decompress.decompress(data)
error: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid distance too far back
```

I've tried using this [online Objective-C compiler](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_objective-c_online.php) along with various classes like `NSUnarchiver`, `NSKeyedUnarchiver`, and `NSPropertyListSerialization`, but no luck, yet. Those all seem to produce output which at least has recognizable strings in it so even if they are used, something else must be going on as well.

The only similarity between different batches has been that they all start with `0x0201`. Everything else seems totally different, even for subsequent updates for the same match, which makes me wonder if there's some obfuscation/encryption going on...

Any tips on where I can go from here?

Comment: What does the *producer* of the data say? It could be most anything, really.

Comment: You're operating under the assumption that `GameData` is textual. Don't forget that Base64 is also used to encode binary data (like image files and executables, for instance). IOW, `GameData` can literally be anything at all, including a proprietary data structure.

Comment: Given it is incompressible the best guess is that is is some other compression scheme or is encrypted. The more random the data the the greater chance it is encrypted.

Comment: What if you class-dump and/or disassemble the app? Does that give any hints? Some code sniffing/hooking using the runtime, perhaps?

Comment: @H2CO3: That would be helpful. I'm poking around inside the app bundle now and figuring out how to decompile the binary.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost certainly some proprietary structure from within the game, serialized out to bytes. `0x0201` could well be versioning for a struct, or just a set of flags that doesn't change across blobs you've seen.

There's no need to assume this is intentionally obfuscated or encrypted data. Standard textual (JSON, XML) and binary (bplist) containers are increasingly ubiquitous and often make one's life easier, but there's nothing nefarious about representing data in a more raw binary format if it's convenient. (See below re: encryption)

To really reverse engineer this in any more detail may be a Sisyphean task: figure out what the values in the binary blob are, numerically or otherwise. Match up the game state data with known (or unknown) values for the game. Do reverse engineering on the code to see what it's writing. That's some varsity stuff, but it's possible.

---

Re: encryption: encryption, or at least signing, *is* common in some parts of online gaming to prevent tampering with game state by bots to gain advantage. Whether that's happening here or not is anyone's guess. A bunch of floating point numbers that represent world positions could look similarly random.

Comment: ah yep looks like it ended up being encryption.